# Some questions about $F(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{z^3-n^3} $

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on this exercize.

Let's define $$F(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{z^3-n^3} $$ Our aim is to study whether and where $F(z)$ is holomorphic and to study his singularities.

Just to make the writing more easy I'll call $ f_n(z) := \frac{z^2}{z^3-n^3}$.

It's easy to see that for $n$ fixed, $f_n(z)$ has 3 poles at $\,\,z_1^n = n$, $\,\,\,\,$ $z_2^n = ne^{i2/3\pi}$, $\,\,\,\,$ $z_3^n = ne^{-i2/3\pi}$.
So for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have these simple poles $z_j^n$ where $j \in \{1,2,3\}$.

To conclude to establish the domain of holomorphy we have to understand if $\sum_n f_n(z)$ converges uniformly in every compact set (so in every closed disk $D_k$ ) included in $\mathbb{C}$ that avoids all the poles $z_j^n$.

But here is exactly where I get stuck.

I've tried to devide the disks in the ones included in $D_1(0)$ (the unit disk centered in the origin) ant the ones out of $D_1(0)$ and finally to use Weierstass convergence theorem:

Inside $D_1(0)$ should be okay:

$$\Big|\frac{z^2}{z^3-n^3} \Big| \le \frac{1}{-|z^3|+|n^3|} \le \frac{1}{n^3} $$

What can I say outside $D_1(0)$ ?

More, what are the singularities of $F(z)$ ? Are they the same of "the union" of the singularities of $f_n$?

Comment: It is not hard to show the convergence under the hypotesis that $d(z,\{n,e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}n,e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}n\})>\varepsilon$. In this way, it's not hard to show that $F$ is an holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-(\mathbb{N}\cup e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\mathbb{N}\cup e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\mathbb{N})$

Comment: Yes, that's how I thought to proceed but honestly I miss how to formalize it with good manners.. If anyone would be so kind to conclude the excercize pointing out all the key points (I'm pretty new to complex analysis) I would appreciate it.

Comment: Consider a disk $D_R = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$. Choose any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k > R$. Show that the tail series $$\sum_{n = k}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{z^3-n^3}$$ converges uniformly on $D_R$. Since the initial part ($0 \leqslant n < k$) contains only finitely many terms, you can conclude that the series converges uniformly on $D_R$ with the poles removed (since at each pole only finitely many of the terms are singular [exactly one term in this case] you don't even need to remove small disks around the poles).

Comment: That's what I was searching for. Thank you. And what about the singularities of the sum $F$?

Comment: The singularities are exactly those that are introduced with the terms of the series: all of the non-negative integers and the others cube  cube roots of $n^3$